# Memcpy Readable Range

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy, memset

Small code bits:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[18];
    char buf2[18];
    int newlength = 16;
    memset(buf, '0', 16);
    for (int i = newlength; i < 18; i++)
        buf[i] = 0x00;

    memcpy(buf2, buf, 18);

    return 0;
}
```

First I want to set a portion of an array to a specific value and then I would like to fill the rest with 0x00. Then I'd like to copy it to another array.

On MS VS2013, I receive a warning as readable range for buf to be between 0 and 15. (Code Analysis for C/C++ Warnings. C6385 Read Overrun) Why? Does memcpy ignore the bits set to 0x00?

Comment: Please provide the warning. Also, what compiler?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I do not see any warnings. Please tell us your compiler+version+options (or whatever tool produced the warning). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90211ae6e2daa5c7

Comment: And by the way, is there a valid reason why you are not using `std::vector`s?

Comment: I'm looking over legacy code, updating large amounts of code is off the table for now. I'm running on MS VS2013. It's from Code Analysis for C/C++ Warnings. C6385 Read Overrun. Should I be concerned?

Comment: I can reproduce it also in MSVC2015

Comment: MS compilers are known to produce many pointless warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message from the code analyzer seems to be based on the principle that the buffer content would be defined alone as output from `memset()`.  It misses the point that the loop after `memset()` completes this input.

If you double click on the warning,  you can get a highlighting of the lines considered for triggering this warning.

But the code you write is correct, so you don't have to worry about the result here.  The online documentation says "might" no "will" :

> This warning indicates that the readable extent of the specified
>   buffer **might** be smaller than the index used to read from it.

**Additional remarks:**

When making what is going on more obvious for the analyzer,  it still brings the same abusive warnings:

```
    memset(buf, '0', 16);
    memset(buf + 16, 0x00, 2);  // for replacing the loop
```

In this case, the analyzer notices the second `memset()`. But as it doesn't affect buf from its beginning, it as an input/output to a buffer operation without taking into consideration the additional length.

Even this kind over-precautiononous code raises the warning:

```
    memset(buf, 0x00, sizeof(buf));   // completeky initalize the buffer
    memset(buf, '0', 16);             // overwrite just the beginning
```

Here, it seems that as soon as a `memxxx()` operation targets the begin of the buffer, the length of that operation is considered to be the sole initialized part.

So, yes the warning is annoying, but trust your code.  I could only get rid of the warning by making really weird an unefficient coding:

```
    memset(buf, 0x00, sizeof(buf));   // 18 bytes get initalized
    memset(buf + 1, '0', 15);         // not begin of buffer 
    buf[0] = '0';                     // not a memxxx() operation
```

Unfortunately the configuration of the analyzer doesn't allow to disable just this single rule, but the whole set of security verification rules.

Comment: I can see that memcpy is working properly, I just don't like that it gives me a warning. :\ I don't like "might" but I guess it'll do. Thanks :)

Comment: @pistachiobk I've played a little bit to find out how to avoid the warning (see the edit):  this warning rule is really unsufficiently defined.  Its only use is to draw attention on potential risks that could need further analyse.

Comment: Switching memcpy(buf2, buf, 18); with std::copy(buf, buf + 18, buf2); clears the warning. It must just be a memcpy/memset issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in compiler / lint tool (depends on who shows you the warning)

Answer (score -1):

You're initializing 16 bytes. You're accessing 18 bytes. It seems to think that the access is reading, even though it shouldn't.

Comment: I initialize the last two bytes in the for loop following memset.

Comment: I get that; that's why I say "it seems to think that the access is reading". I'm just not sure why it seems to think that.